# How does dict.pop() detect if an optional argument has been passed?

Tags: python

```
d = dict()
d.pop('hello', None) # No exception thrown
d.pop('hello', 0)    # No exception thrown
d.pop('hello')       # KeyError
```

I had thought that in Python we usually tested whether a default argument was passed by testing the argument with some sort of default value.

I can't think of any other 'natural' default value that `dict.pop` would have used.

Is `dict.pop` using some other means to test for the optional argument? Or is it using some more esoteric default value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `dict` is implemented in C, so Python semantics don't really apply. Otherwise, I'd say look at the source in any case.

However, a good pattern for this is to use a sentinel as the default value. That will never match against anything passed in, so you can be sure that if you get that value, you only have one argument.

```
sentinel = object()

def get(value, default=sentinel):
    if default is sentinel:
       # etc
```

This is an appropriate use of `is`, as you want to be sure you're checking for the exact sentinel object, not just something that evaluates equal to it.

Comment: Thank you! I would also made the sentinel private, called it _sentinel, so that it is not exported.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this probably.

```
def pop(_dict, val, *args):
    if val in _dict:
        return _dict.pop(val)
    elif args:
        return args[0]
    else:
        raise KeyError()
```

example:

```
In [5]: pop({}, 'a')

KeyError:

In [6]: pop({}, 'a', 0)
Out[6]: 0
```

Comment: My thoughts also but this implementation allows more args, ie `pop({}, 'a', 0, 1`) raises no error while `dict.pop` does